# Can interacting quantum field theory describe more than just scattering?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, path-integral, interactions, s-matrix-theory

From my understanding we do not yet know how to make much out of interacting QFT other than scattering amplitude at asymptotic infinity. (Correct me if I misunderstand.) But path integral, in principle should allow us to compute different sorts of transition probabilities. So is lack of understanding more about constructing observables such that we can test with measurements? That is, is this lack of understanding about our current lack of how to interpret states at times not sent to asymptotic infinity?

Comment: We can compute the mass of the proton by numerically simulating the path integral of QCD. We can compute the critical exponents of thermodynamic phase transitions by using the epsilon expansion and the renormalization group for statistical field theories. We can compute the anomalous magnetic moment of the muon. We can compute the equation of state and the conductivity of QED and QCD plasmas. None of these things are scattering amplitudes.