# Eigenfunctionals and their application in physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, eigenvalue, correlation-functions, functional-derivatives

Is there any sensible meaning of the term *eigenfunctionals*? The object I want to describe is a solution to the following equation

$$ {\mathscr D}_x F[g] = f(x) F[g] $$

where $ {\mathscr D}_x$ is an operator that maps functionals to functionals (e.g. a functional derivative $\frac{\delta}{\delta g(x)}$), $F$ is an eigenfunctional of ${\mathscr D}_x$, $f(x)$ is a corresponding eigenfunction, and $g(x)$ is some other function. Of course, this is rather a try to make sense of this term or to motivate thinking about it than a proper definition since I cannot find any. Additionally, is there an application of this concept in physics, e.g. when using functional methods in the path integral formalism of quantum field theory? A special case I encountered during studying correlation functions would be:

$$F[\phi(x)] = \exp \left( \int dx \, \phi(x) \, h(x) \right) $$

$$\frac{\delta F[\phi(x)]}{\delta \phi(y)} = h(y) F[\phi(x)]$$

However, a generalization of the idea would probably be fruitful.

Comment: This is a [Schwinger-Dyson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation). See [this PSE post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/395689/84967) for the standard use in physics.

Comment: In the Schrödinger picture of a quantum field theory, one has wavefunctionals of the fields which are eigenfunctionals of the Hamiltonian. Here is a nice introduction: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/055032138590210X

Comment: Thank you, accidentalfouriertransform, for the reference to the great post, which will be helpful in understanding the Schwinger-Dyson equation! However, I rather intended to get some insights into the mathematical properties of the more general equation I proposed. Do you know of another application of this kind of equation?

Comment: @SethWhitsitt: Thanks for pointing out the connection to the Schrödinger picture of QFT which I haven't heard of before. I will check if I will be able to find the mathematical foundation for its defining equation which should be equivalent to my question.

Comment: @CarloTasillo My answers to the questions https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441251 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439434 both mention this kind of formulation (Schrodinger functional formulation of QFT).

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395051/energies-of-this-field-hamiltonian?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142180/schrodinger-wave-functional-quantum-fields-solving-functional-gaussian-integ?rq=1). [Jackiw's review](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/22/056/22056871.pdf) pp 78-143.